# pickle raises EOFError on Ubuntu 14.04 but works on Mac OS and Linux Mint

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, ubuntu, pickle

I am saving some big data using Python's pickle module. To be more precise I am dumping two objects to the same pickle-file as follows:

```
def save(sim):
    if sim.tstamp > 0:
        with open(filepath(sim.identifier), 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(sim.serialize(), f)
            pickle.dump(sim, f)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Simulation not yet simulated")
```

`sim` is a self-written class which has different attributes and a method called `serialize()`. This method converts all attributes and its values to a dictionary by using something like:

```
def serialize(self):
    keys = ['height', 'diameter', 'rpm', 'packaging']
    serialized = dict((key, getattr(self, key)) for key in keys)
    serialized['sectors'] = [sector.serialize() for sector in self.sectors]
    return serialized
```

So basically `sim.serialize()` returns a dictionary which is dumped to the pickle file as the first object. The second object is the sim-object itself. This is due to the large size of each sim object. Providing the dictionary enables a kind of summary in order to prevent loading the complete simulation if not really necessary.

To load the data from the pickle file I use:

```
def load(fname, params_only=False):
    simulation = find(fname) # find returns file name
    try:
        with open(simulation, 'r') as json_file:
            return json.load(json_file)
    except (UnicodeDecodeError, ValueError) as e:
        with open(simulation, 'rb') as pickle_file:
            params = pickle.load(pickle_file)
            if params_only:
                return params
            return pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

Since an older API is capable of JSON-files as well I need to handle both JSON- and pickle-files.

Dumping the objects works as desired (no error messages are raised). However, when requesting some data graphs the API needs to unpickle the data which raises the following error:

```
[2016-08-07 14:39:34,637] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/simulations/20160807_123707581/heatflux_distribution.png [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/abkos/abkosproject/abkos/_tools.py", line 36, in load
   return json.load(json_file)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 265, in load
   return loads(fp.read(),
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
   response = self.full_dispatch_request()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
   rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
   reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
   raise value
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
   rv = self.dispatch_request()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
   return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
 File "./app.py", line 118, in plot_figure
   img = plotter(identifier, figname, request.args.items())
 File "./app.py", line 122, in plotter
   sim = Simulation.from_file(identifier)
 File "/home/abkos/abkosproject/abkos/calculation.py", line 56, in from_file
   params_or_simulation = load(fname, params_only=new)
 File "/home/abkos/abkosproject/abkos/_tools.py", line 42, in load
   return pickle.load(pickle_file)
_pickle.UnpicklingError
10.0.2.2 - - [07/Aug/2016 14:39:34] "GET /api/simulations/20160807_123707581/heatflux_distribution.png HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[2016-08-07 14:39:38,691] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/simulations/20160807_123707581/heatmap_axial_temperatures.png [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/abkos/abkosproject/abkos/_tools.py", line 36, in load
   return json.load(json_file)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 265, in load
   return loads(fp.read(),
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
   response = self.full_dispatch_request()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
   rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
   reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
   raise value
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
   rv = self.dispatch_request()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
   return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
 File "./app.py", line 118, in plot_figure
   img = plotter(identifier, figname, request.args.items())
 File "./app.py", line 122, in plotter
   sim = Simulation.from_file(identifier)
 File "/home/abkos/abkosproject/abkos/calculation.py", line 56, in from_file
   params_or_simulation = load(fname, params_only=new)
 File "/home/abkos/abkosproject/abkos/_tools.py", line 42, in load
   return pickle.load(pickle_file)
EOFError
10.0.2.2 - - [07/Aug/2016 14:39:38] "GET /api/simulations/20160807_123707581/heatmap_axial_temperatures.png HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The code is working fine on both MacOS and Linux Mint using Python 3.4.3. However, it does not work on Ubuntu 14.04 (Python 3.4.3).

Any ideas about where to start to investigate the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was not able to find any coding errors I compared the three systems to each other and found out that there were nearly identically from a software point-of-view. All of them are using Python 3.4.3 64-bit and pickle is part of Python's default modules.

So I came to the conclusion that this might be a hardware related problem. Since both the MacOS-machine and the Mint-machine are 'real' machines and the Ubuntu one is a VM only I compared general hardware specs like number of CPUs and RAM.

The real machines are equipped with 8 GB of RAM resp. 12 GB for the Mint one. So I increased the RAM of the VM from about 1 GB to 3 GB and everything works fine.

So even there was no `MemoryError` or similar raised, `EOFError` can be related to memory.